# Making A Collection of Files Searchable

Tags: pdf

I have a request, one of which I am not certain attainable. Recently I have gone from taking notes in Evernote, to just taking notes using my latex distribution, by reason of the fact that whenever I had to type of an equation in Evernote, I had to go to the website http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, and generate an image, which I found particularly annoying. I also like using latex because it is allows for a lot of customization. However, one thing that I did enjoy about Evernote was the fact that all my notes were contained in one area, and every single note was capable of being searched at once.

Here comes my request: Does anyone know of a way of making all of the pdf files that I generate from my latex distribution searchable, without actually having to open each individual pdf, and searching through it?

Comment: This depends on the type of operating system you're working within.  If you're using a Linux box or a Mac, you can search your text files from the command line using `grep -rIn <search string>`.  This will recursively look through the directory hierarchy from whichever directory to you start the search.  It's been a while since I've done anything like this on a windows machine; so, I'll leave that for someone else to answer.

Comment: I am in fact using a Windows machine. Thank you, A.Ellett, for the hope, however, seeing as you are saying that it is possible :)

Comment: Have you considered `cygwin`?  It gives you a Linux-like terminal.  When I had a windows machine, I did a lot of my work within `cygwin`.  It allowed me to compile LaTeX documents, run perl scripts, and do file searches as suggested in my earlier comment.

Comment: @A.Ellett: `grep` is the wrong command for searching _pdfs_, as they can contain binary.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I wasn't intending to suggest searching for the pdf's.  I assume since the OP was creating the pdf's, a grep search would find the original text files used to create them.